# POI XSSF - Can't add pictures to existing xlsx file

Tags: apache-poi, xlsx, xssf

At this line:

```
wbk.addPicture(iconData, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
```

I get this exception:

*org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.PartAlreadyExistsException: A part with the name '/xl/media/image2.png' already exists : Packages shall not contain equivalent part names and package implementers shall neither create nor recognize packages with equivalent part names. [M1.12]*

That same line of code has worked perfectly before. If I open the xlsx file with 7zip, there is actually a image named image2.png, which is correct and is another picture added by hand with Excel. It's like it tries to add the new image with the same name as the existing image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: 3.17, I can't upgrade to 4+ until I replace the deprecated methods with the new ones in 4+

Comment: There were several bug fixes around this sort of thing since 3.17, so you do really need to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I was editing a file that was saved with LibreOffice 6.1, after opening it in Excel and saving it, it worked.

Also, like @Gagravarr said, a upgrade will be better and will probably work without needing to use Excel only